# WordPress - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required. Failed to open stream

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

I tried to setup the localhost for my website. I downloaded source & database for my live site.

Using xampp I'm making the localhost and due to large database file I upload it using the command prompt. And I changed the config file and changed the URL on database to localhost URL.

Then I check the localhost URL of my website, it shows below error:

**Warning:** require(C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite/wp-includes/sodium_compat/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-includes\compat.php on line 338

**Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite/wp-includes/sodium_compat/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-includes\compat.php:338 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-settings.php(34): require() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-config.php(103): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsites\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-includes\compat.php on line 338

What is this error?? How to resolve it, because I'm new to the development. I want to resolve this error as soon as possible.

I can't able to find the solution yet.